# Why handlesubmit is not working on this react-hook-form implementation?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have this form:

```
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Input
          onChange={(ev) => handlePriceInputChange(ev)}
          type="number"
          value={price}
          innerRef={register("voucherPrice", { required: true })}
        ></Input>
        <p>{errors.voucherPrice?.message}</p>

        <Button
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ mt: 1, mr: 1 }}
          type="submit"
        >
          {"Continue"}
        </Button>
      </form>
```

I have configurated react-hook-form like:

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("?", data);}
```

I am trying to see `console.log("?", data)` on the dev tools console, and I get:

```
Warning: Unexpected ref object provided for input. Use either a ref-setter function or React.createRef().
```

But it doesn't seem to reach the console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `register` is incorrect, since v7 [it will return an object instead of a ref](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Registerfields), which can be spread to a component. Right now you are trying to pass an object to `innerRef` instead of an actual `ref`, hence the error.

In your case you should use `<Controller />` if you want to pass the `ref` to your `innerRef` prop.

```js
<Controller
  name="voucherPrice"
  control={control}
  rules={{ required: true }}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => 
    <Input
      {...field}
      type="number"
      innerRef={ref}
    /> 
  }
/>
```

Comment: I don't understand how to pass the onChange method through `field` , I get an error when I try this code ` Unexpected token, expected "," (118:37)
`

Comment: Sorry, the template had a syntax error. I updated the answer.

Comment: thank you, although I do not understand how could I input my onChange function

Comment: What do you mean by input your onChange function? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: when a user writes anything on the input, this function `handlePriceInputChange` triggers

Comment: moreover, with the example, my onSubmit function does not trigger

Comment: When using `react-hook-form` you don't need to setup an extra `onChange` handler like `handlePriceInputChange` to manage state changes as this will be done by `react-hook-form` itself. So in the `<Controller />` example the `field` object has an `onChange` property which is spread to your `<Input />` component. [Here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) you can read more about `<Controller />`.

Comment: This is also the reason why your `onSubmit` function is not triggered, because your `<Input />` has a required rule. And as you are not linking the `onChange` handler to `react-hook-form`'s internal form state it won't get updated and the required rule is still failing and therefore `onSubmit` won't get called.